# Are links to Amazon/Ebay/Marketplace okay

Tags: discussion, editing

I [edited](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/posts/23448/revisions) this [answer](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/23448/22086) so that the referenced books would now have links to their respective pages on Amazon should any user decide to purchase the books.

I assume that the original answerer is not affiliated with either work. Is this okay to do to answers? (Or questions too, I guess)

Comment: Just a point of interest - [Stack Exchange strips referral codes from Amazon links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317994/401104) (so we don't need to worry about that spam angle).

Comment: @EmC Are they still doing it? The accepted answer is a bit confusing about that ^^'

Comment: @Ælis ah true - the comment there is more direct: "This in effect strips referral codes from all raw amazon links." [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334767/given-that-stack-exchange-no-longer-adds-its-referral-code-to-rewritten-amazon-l) linked meta has a lot more context about the whole program too.

Answer (score 6):

ISBN's are the easiest way to uniquely identify a book.

Instead of a seller site, I'd link to an ISBN lookup, like [this](https://isbnsearch.org/isbn/9780136019701). Or maybe link to a google books lookup of the ISBN like [this](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=isbn%3A0136019706). The beauty of these two is that they in no way support the author or push the book itself. Clicking into them will solely get you more information on the novel (or an avenue to purchase/find more about the author if you so desire).

I think secondary to this would be a third party website like wikipedia. And lastly would be an author or book website like [Ælis mentions](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3901/11811), **if you can confirm that they are legitimate.** But like seller sites, these usually have some amount of traffic tracking that users may not want to unknowingly jump into.

Regardless of what you choose, I do think we should try to avoid directly linking to seller sites.

Answer (score 5):

I think it was nice that you added those links, however, I'm not really comfortable with the idea of them leading to Amazon.

In such a situation, I think it would be best if we could:

1. Link to the author's website

If not possible:

2. Link to a "neutral" website (one that doesn't actually sell the book) like Wikipedia

If still not possible:

3. Link to a selling place that proposes the book (like Amazon)

---

So, in this specific case, I believe we should link to [this](https://www.lowndes.com/howtotalk/) (author's website) and [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Voss) (Wikipedia page of the autor) instead of Amazon.

Comment: Excellent idea to link to author's site or Wikipedia entry. I have edited the answer with the links you found.